# How to display a number with many decimals and year correctly

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, csv

I have a table in "import_csv_2.csv" as follows:

```
No. Year    W(G)
1   2010    0.02110333
2   2008    0.02082747
3   2006    0.02037291
...


\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    col sep=comma,
columns/Subject/.style={string type}, 
%   columns/Math/.style={string type},
%   columns/Lit/.style={string type},
    %draw the line among head rows 
    every head row/.style={
        before row = \toprule,
        after row = \midrule
    },
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
]{import_csv_2.csv}
```

After I compiled, I got the "Year" displays as "number" (for e.g : 2010 displays as 2,010). And my 3rd column display with scientific notation (for e.g : 0.02110333 displays as 2.11*10-2).

How can I tell Latex display my tables exactly as same as it looks like in my .csv format?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Um, what you showed is not an actual CSV file. It's not comma-separated.

Comment: Hi, @RobinGreen I am using the CSV file as follows `No.,Year,W(G)
1,2010,0.0211
2,2008,0.0208
3,2006,0.0204
4,2004,0.0188
5,2002,0.0176
6,2000,0.0170
7,1998,0.0163
8,1995,0.0141
9,1993,0.0130
10,1991,0.0127
11,1989,0.0115`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
    header=true,
    columns/No/.style={},
    columns/Year/.style={},
    columns/W/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=8},
    set thousands separator={}
]{import_csv_2.csv}
```

`set thousands separator`  fixes the second column

`fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=8`  fixes the third column

This is the complete latex file I used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
    header=true,
    columns/No/.style={},
    columns/Year/.style={},
    columns/W/.style={fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=8},% fixes the 3rd col
    set thousands separator={}% fixes the 2nd col
]{import_csv_2.csv}
\end{document}
```

Compiled with TexnicCenter 1.0 and MixTex 2.9

CSV file consists of:

```
No.,Year,W
1,2010,0.02110333
2,2008,0.02082747
3,2006,0.02037291
```

Comment: Thanks Dries. The second column is fixed correctly. However, the 3rd column still displays in scientific notation even I tried to increase "precision = 9, or 10".

Comment: I've noticed pgfplots was run in backwards compatability mode in my case. 

Does it work if you add \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} to the start of the latex file?

Comment: Hi, I add `\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}`, unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem. P/S: The reason i chose 1.8 is that my program showed warning lacking of `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` in my previous run. And if i use 1.9, it shows error. Do i miss anything else in my program?